# how to make double summary statistics thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, java-8, stream, thread-safety

DoubleSummaryStatistics summaryStats = mTransactionSet.stream()
                    .mapToDouble(this::getPrice).summaryStatistics();

I have above code but javadoc says that DoubleSummaryStatistics is not thread safe.

So how do i ensure that multiple threads when act on mTransactionSet will work properly ?

Any pointers would be much appreciated . Thank you

Comment: So, do you want to make the instance of DoubleSummaryStatistics thread-safe, or the code iterating on mTransactionSet thread-safe? You're contradicting yourself in your question. In both cases, we would need to know how the variable is hared between threads, if it's mutated somewhere, etc.

Comment: i have 2 rest api's one of them will update the mTransactionSet(ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()) where as the other  will caluculate summary - in each request am trying to caluculate the summary operating on mTransactionSet . So the above piece of code would it be thread safe , is there any approach to make it thread safe apart from using read write lock ?

Comment: The Set returned by ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet() is thread-safe. You shouldn't have anything to do to make your code thread-safe.

Answer (score 2):

`DoubleSummaryStatistics` is intended to be used in streams, in particular in code of form:

```
DoubleSummaryStatistics stats = stream.collect(Collectors.summarizingDouble());
```

or, when you have a `DoubleStream`:

```
DoubleSummaryStatistics stats = stream.summaryStatisitics();
```

This works for both sequential and parallel streams. The parallel streams will not use a single `DoubleSummaryStatistics` object to collect the data, it will use a different instance in each thread and later combine the data with `DoubleSummaryStatistics::combine`.

If you want to use `DoubleSummaryStatistics` in a stream, you don't have to think about all this stuff. Java does it for you. If you want to use it yourself in a multithreaded environment, use the same approach as parallel streams: each thread should use its own `DoubleSummaryStatistics` object, and in the end, all data are combined.

Or you synchronize all access to the object of course, but that will probably will be very slow.

Comment: thank you , few questions - i have a rest api which will receive huge number of requests - in each request am trying to caluculate the summary operating on ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet() . So the above piece of code would it be thread safe , is there any approach to make it thread safe apart from using read write lock ?